# Struct creation issue

Tags: c++

I have a struct declared like this:

```
struct sExample {
  int something;
  char somethingElse[32];
  bool another;
  // many other fields
};
```

It has more of `int`, `char[]` and `bool`. Now let's face the problem. First of all I created a class which uses temporary variable of type `sExample`.

```
class ExClass {
  void fun() {
    sExample myStruct;
    // Initialize some of the struct fields (just some of them!)
    strcpy(myStruct.somethingElse, "TEXT");
    // Use struct in function that may read or modify it
    globalFunction(&myStruct);
  }
}
```

It worked just fine, but later I decided that `myStruct` should be available longer then just in function fun, so I moved it to class members:

```
class ExClass {
  sExample myStruct;
  void fun() {
    // Same code as above
    // Initialize some of the struct fields (just some of them!)
    strcpy(myStruct.somethingElse, "TEXT");
    // Use struct in function that may read or modify it
    globalFunction(&myStruct);
  }
}
```

And here is the problem. Call to `globalFunction` causes segfault (this is a function from an external 3rd party library, so I can't identify where exactly the problem is).
I've also tried initializing struct with use of `= {0}`, but it didn't help. What can be wrong?
I'm using Gcc 4.9, C++11.
Anybody can explain what is the problem here?

Comment: You should read much more about C++. Use `std::string`. Have your own constructors and detructors. Know about the [rule of five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)

Comment: Also, compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use the debugger** (`gdb`) & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: If you cannot change the `struct` you'll better zero (with `memset`) it before using it. At least you'll get more reproducible behavior

Comment: initialize all fields of myStruct. Otherwise, no differene in your example between the local version and the data member version

Comment: If `ExClass` goes out of scope, the members also go out of scope.  You didn't show where you instantiated an `ExClass` object and how it's used.

Comment: We can assume that ExClass object doesn't go out of scope. It's just simple one threaded application. And sorry - I cannot modify the struct members.

Comment: @user1405687 *We can assume that ExClass object doesn't go out of scope.* -- Why should we assume this?  You have an issue of a function not working, you didn't post anything other than a class.  We don't know what your code consists of.

Comment: What does this third party globalFunction do exactly?  you need to supply more information.

Comment: The other members of `myStruct` are uninitialized in your example. Change to `sExample myStruct {};`.  Could you show some more code about how you are using the struct, and describe if the global function saves the pointer to the struct?

Comment: To get a good answer straight away, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

If that is your only change, then your issue is that you're calling `fun()` on a invalid instance of `ExClass`. Or you forgot to new the class or it already is deleted/went out of scope.

F.e. this [Ideone](http://ideone.com/H5zJ3j) example works perfectly, because `A a` is created on stack inside `fun()`. But once you move the declaration of `a` to class level, you will get an exception because `*b` is not instantiated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    int data;
    A() : data(123) { }
};

class B {
public:
    void fun() {
        A a;
        cout << a.data;
    }
};

int main() {
    B* b; // b points to random memory, thus is an invalid instance
    b->fun(); // this still works because fun doesn't access any member of B
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Usually `b->fun()` would fail regardless of any `B` implementation details. Wouldn't it?

Comment: <Looking at the ideone example> Hm. :-)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider it causes undefined behaviour, meaning anything can happen. Typically the compiler will just generate the same code for `b->fun` regardless of whether `b` is initialized or not, and in this example it so happens that the address pointed to by `b` was not used in the code generated by the compiler.

Comment: @M.M *typically*? The compiler will just generate one `fun` proc and call it while passing along the `b` instance. When that proc doesn't use anything from that instance, nothing will fail. Adding an extra check would only slow down the code.

Comment: I haven't surveyed all possible past and future compilers, and the C++ Standard doesn't mandate the behaviour you described. Another possibility would be that an optimization pass removes this entire section of code, because it knows that using `->` on an uninitialized pointer causes undefined behaviour.